# `--chown` option of COPY and ADD doesn't allow variables. There exists a workaround?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-copy

In a Dockerfile, the common way to copy a directory as a non-root user (e.g $UID 1000) is the following:

```
COPY --chown=1000:1000 /path/to/host/dir/ /path/to/container/dir
```

However, I want to use variables instead. For example

```
ARG USER_ID=1000
ARG GROUP_ID=1000
COPY --chown=${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} /path/to/host/dir/ /path/to/container/dir
```

But this is not possible. There exist a workaround?

**Note** I know that a possible workaround could be to copy the directory as root and then run chown on the directory (variables works fine with `RUN`). However, the size of the image will grow just for the use of chown in a separate command.

Comment: I believe you can do it with more recent versions of docker - I'm copying files the same way you do (`COPY --chown=${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}`), and it works just fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a user before running the `--chown`;

```
mkdir -p test && cd test
mkdir -p path/to/host/dir/
touch path/to/host/dir/myfile
```

Create your Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox

ARG USER_ID=1000
ARG GROUP_ID=1000

RUN addgroup -g ${GROUP_ID} mygroup \
 && adduser -D myuser -u ${USER_ID} -g myuser -G mygroup -s /bin/sh -h /

COPY --chown=myuser:mygroup /path/to/host/dir/ /path/to/container/dir
```

Build the image

```
docker build -t example .
```

Or build it with a custom UID/GID:

```
docker build -t example --build-arg USER_ID=1234 --build-arg GROUP_ID=2345 .
```

And verify that the file was chown'ed

```
docker run --rm example ls -la /path/to/container/dir

total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 myuser   mygroup       4096 Dec 22 16:08 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Dec 22 16:08 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser   mygroup          0 Dec 22 15:51 myfile
```

Verify that it has the correct uid/gid:

```
docker run --rm example ls -lan /path/to/container/dir

total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 1234     2345          4096 Dec 22 16:08 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 0        0             4096 Dec 22 16:08 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 1234     2345             0 Dec 22 15:51 myfile
```

> **Note**: there is an open feature-request for adding this functionality:
>   [issue #35018](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35018) "Allow COPY command's --chown to be dynamically populated via ENV or ARG"

Comment: I almost have the same problem. In the sense that `myuser` can't be substituted by a variable like `$USERNAME`. However, it's not a problem for me to have a fixed name of the user. What I needed was a variable user id and group id. Long story short: you solved my problem but only because the username can be fixed in my use case.

Comment: Do you want to change the UID/GID because (during development) you'd want to make them match your local user (and bind-mount your source inside the container)? You may be interested in this dirty trick (from @bmitch); https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018eu/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#49 

The whole presentation is worth reading (you can also find it on GitHub https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/presentations)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used my UID and GID numbers and it works as I do have the same non-root account in the DEV and PROD environments.

```
COPY --chown=1000:1000 /path/to/host/dir/ /path/to/container/dir
```

And you can find the user and group IDs with the linux command: id